# Why is it justified to focus on gauge transformations constant at spatial infinity in QCD instantons?

Tags: gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, instantons, non-perturbative

In the context of Yang-Mills theories and QCD instantons, much of the literature and conventional treatment hinges on the consideration of gauge transformations that remain constant at spatial infinity. This is particularly prevalent when discussing topological invariants, such as the winding number:

$$ n(\Omega) = \frac{1}{24 \pi^2} \int_{S^3} d^3 S \, \epsilon_{ijk} \, \text{tr} \left( \left( \Omega^{-1} \partial_i \Omega \right) \left( \Omega^{-1} \partial_j \Omega \right) \left( \Omega^{-1} \partial_k \Omega \right) \right) $$
where $\Omega$ denotes the gauge transformation.

My query is:

On what grounds is it justified to predominantly focus on this specific subset of gauge transformations (those constant at spatial infinity)? Are there inherent issues or complications that arise when considering more general gauge transformations that do not satisfy this constraint?
In essence, I'm trying to understand the motivation or necessity behind this specific choice in the treatment of QCD instantons. Any explanations, references, or insights that shed light on the rationale behind this focus would be greatly appreciated.